# How to download all files (but not HTML) from a website using wget?

Tags: ubuntu, download, wget

How to use `wget` and get all the files from website?

I need all files except the webpage files like HTML, PHP, ASP etc.

Comment: Even if you want to download php, it is not possible using wget. We can get only raw HTML using wget. I guess you know the reason

Comment: **NB:** Always check with `wget --spider` first, and always add `-w 1` (or more `-w 5`) so you don't flood the other person's server.

Comment: How could I download all the pdf files in this page? http://pualib.com/collection/pua-titles-a.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 296, accepted):

To filter for specific file extensions:

```
wget -A pdf,jpg -m -p -E -k -K -np http://site/path/
```

Or, if you prefer long option names:

```
wget --accept pdf,jpg --mirror --page-requisites --adjust-extension --convert-links --backup-converted --no-parent http://site/path/
```

This will mirror the site, but the files without `jpg` or `pdf` extension will be automatically removed.

Comment: If you just want to download files without whole directories architecture, you can use **-nd** option.

Comment: what do each of the flags mean?

Comment: I think `--accept` is case-sensitive, so you would have to do `--accept pdf,jpg,PDF,JPG`

Comment: not sure if this is with a new version of `wget` but you have to specify a `--progress` type, e.g. `--progress=dot`

Comment: @Flimm you can also use `--ignore-case` flag to make `--accept` case insensitive.

Comment: @jamis, I corrected the post.  `--progress` is not the longer option name for `-p`.  It should be `--page-requisites` as in the `man`.

Comment: Thanks, this command allows me to download all artifacts from jfrog-artifactory. you saved my life dude

Comment: You probably don't want -E with --accept (or -A). If the accept type is plain text then -E will rename it to name.html. Then it won't match the --accept and will be deleted.

Comment: I tried to run this command for ```https://www.balluff.com``` and it successfully downloads several pdfs but it misses the ones on this page https://www.balluff.com/en/de/service/downloads/brochures-and-catalogues/#/?data=category%3Dd0001. For example this: https://assets.balluff.com/WebBinary1/LIT_CAT_CATALOG_VOLUME_SENSORS_1_ZH_A19_DRW_943859_00_000.pdf these were the ones I was the most interested in. Any idea why? @diabloneo

Comment: I tried to run this command for ```https://www.balluff.com``` and it successfully downloads several pdfs but it misses the ones on this page https://www.balluff.com/en/de/service/downloads/brochures-and-catalogues/#/?data=category%3Dd0001. For example this: https://assets.balluff.com/WebBinary1/LIT_CAT_CATALOG_VOLUME_SENSORS_1_ZH_A19_DRW_943859_00_000.pdf these were the ones I was the most interested in. Any idea why? @Harsh

Answer (score 91):

This downloaded the **entire** website for me:

```
wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p -E -e robots=off -U mozilla http://site/path/
```

Comment: +1 for `-e robots=off`! This finally fixed my problem! :) Thanks

Comment: The `--random-wait` option is genius ;)

Comment: @izilotti Can the site owner find out if you WGET their site files with this method?

Comment: @whatIsperfect It's definitely possible.

Comment: @JackNicholsonn How will the site owner know? The agent used was Mozilla, which means all headers will go in as a Mozilla browser, thus detecting wget as used would not be possible? Please correct if I'm wrong. thanks

Comment: @Elias7 Will the site owner know? Yes. The site owner may embed a link that is excluded by the robots tag or invisible to humans. The site owner may go even farther and [poison the off-limit path](https://perishablepress.com/blackhole-bad-bots/).

Comment: It **works**! But it's a BFG approach. Downloads **everything**.

Answer (score 64):

```
wget -m -p -E -k -K -np http://site/path/
```

*man page* will tell you what those options do.

`wget` will only follow links, if there is no link to a file from the index page, then `wget` will not know about its existence, and hence not download it. ie. it helps if all files are linked to in web pages or in directory indexes.

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

It copies whole site and I need only files (i.e. txt,pdf,image etc.) in the website

Answer (score 28):

I was trying to download zip files linked from [Omeka's themes page](http://omeka.org/add-ons/themes/) - pretty similar task. This worked for me:

```
wget -A zip -r -l 1 -nd http://omeka.org/add-ons/themes/
```

- `-A`: only accept zip files
- `-r`: recurse
- `-l 1`: one level deep (ie, only files directly linked from this page)
- `-nd`: don't create a directory structure, just download all the files into this directory.

All the answers with `-k`, `-K`, `-E` etc options probably haven't really understood the question, as those as for rewriting HTML pages to make a local structure, renaming `.php` files and so on. Not relevant.

To literally get all files *except* `.html` etc:

```
wget -R html,htm,php,asp,jsp,js,py,css -r -l 1 -nd http://yoursite.com
```

Comment: `-A` is case-sensitive, I think, so you would have to do `-A zip,ZIP`

Answer (score 9):

**I know this topic is very old, but I fell here at 2021** looking for a way to download all Slackware files from a mirror (http://ftp.slackware-brasil.com.br/slackware64-current/).

After reading all the answers, the best option for me was:

```
wget -m -p -k -np -R '*html*,*htm*,*asp*,*php*,*css*' -X 'www' http://ftp.slackware-brasil.com.br/slackware64-current/
```

I had to use `*html*` instead of just `html` to avoid downloads like `index.html.tmp`.

Please forgive me for resurrecting this topic, I thought it might be useful to someone other than me, and my doubt is very similar to @Aniruddhsinh's question.

Answer (score 7):

You may try:

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla --content-disposition --mirror --convert-links -E -K -p http://example.com/
```

Also you can add:

```
-A pdf,ps,djvu,tex,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,gz,ppt,mp4,avi,zip,rar
```

to accept the specific extensions, or to reject only specific extensions:

```
-R html,htm,asp,php
```

or to exclude the specific areas:

```
-X "search*,forum*"
```

If the files are ignored for robots (e.g. search engines), you've to add also:  `-e robots=off`

Answer (score 5):

Try this. It always works for me

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR WEBSITE-URL
```

Answer (score 5):

```
wget -m -A * -pk -e robots=off www.mysite.com/
```

this will download all type of files locally and point to them from the html file
and it will ignore robots file