# wget all images from a single web page

Tags: image, web, download, wget

Is there a way to get wget to download all of the image files directly linked from a given web page?

In this particular case, the web page contains several "img" tags and I just want to download those images.  I can't seem to get this to work with any combination of -r, -l, -p, -A, etc.  No matter what I do wget completely ignores the images, even when I try specifying -r -p -A jpg.

When I'm using -r it also seems to generate a lot of requests for the same page but with a variety of different query strings attached.  It would be nice if I could avoid this too somehow.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: can you please mention the url so we can help you ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download all files from a website using wget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-website-using-wget)

Answer (score 0):

`wget -nd -p --accept=.jpg <url>`

`-nd` will not create directories
`-p` says download the requisites for the page

This does not do recursive so it will only download `jpg` images for the current page, you can add `-r` if you want to do all the pages