# Saving a complete webpage on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: web, save

My aim is to save a webpage on Chrome or Firefox as a complete webpage in the save as dialogue box when prompted. The saving is done without any issues; however when I click on the html file generated together with the included folder I see a blank page be it Chrome or Firefox. Why is this so? How can I remedy this issue?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: After akm's answer I was able to get the map displayed and the JSON file containing the coordinates of the markers on the map downloaded alongside. However, when I launch the local copy the markers are no longer displayed. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that i could imagine in you case could, either the webapge you are dowanloding has some dependency file such as some some JS, CSS or other file due to which it may not get formmatted.

I think you could use wget bash utility on your terminal to mirror the required files as will along with the page you need.

```
wget -mk http://SITE_URL/directory
```

Futher you may like to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-website-using-wget).

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: By the way what functionality the option -mk provide over the default behaviour?

Comment: It did display the webpage done in this way, yet the embedded Java code did not work. Though I figured out that the JSON file was downloaded alongside.

Comment: @Vesnog it would be nice if you would refer to the man page of wget it will present you with the proper information.