# How can I only display a progess bar with wget in vagrant provisioning?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, wget

I am using `wget` in `bash script` when I provision `ubuntu` machine with `vagrant` like

```
wget https://www.example.com/test.zip -O test.zip
```

As this file is big, the screen which I see with vagrant is like this:

```
==> default: 569600K .......... .....
==> default: ..... .......... .
==> default: ......... .......
==> default: ... 47% 1.18M 47m34s
==> default: 569650K .......... ...
==> default: ....... .........
==> default: . .......... .....
==> default: ..... 47% 75.4K 47m34s
==> default: 569700K .......... .
==> default: ........
==> default: . .......
==> default: ... .......... ...
==> default: ....... 47% 41.9M 47m34s
==> default: 569750K .........
==> default: . .......... .....
==> default: ....
==> default: .
==> default: ...
==> default: ....... .
==> default: ......... 47% 42.8M 47m34s
==> default: 569800K .......
==> default: ... .......... ...
==> default: ....... .
==> default: ........
```

This keeps coming every second and all important information is lost.

Is there any way I can see only a progress bar and no other junk information every second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download all files (but no HTML) from a website using wget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-but-no-html-from-a-website-using-wget)

Comment: @Sneal This is not even close to duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The best you could do - use `--no-verbose` (or `-nv`) option:

```
wget --no-verbose https://www.example.com/test.zip -O test.zip
```

This will turn off all unimportant output (progress bar) from wget.

Or use `--progress=bar:force`:

```
wget --progress=bar:force https://www.example.com/test.zip -O test.zip
```

This will make output look like this:

```
...
Python-3.5.0.tar.xz   7%[>                     ]   1013K   343KB/s             
Python-3.5.0.tar.xz  11%[=>                    ]   1,54M   346KB/s   eta 38s   
Python-3.5.0.tar.xz  14%[==>                   ]   1,99M   316KB/s   eta 38s   
Python-3.5.0.tar.xz  18%[===>                  ]   2,59M   306KB/s   eta 37s 
...
```