# How to download only mp3 files from a website using wget?

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I would like to download all mp3 files from a website using wget. But the website is having pages that end with **.aspx** extension. I tried the following

```
wget -r -c -nd -l1 --no-parent -A mp3 http://ww2.example.com/audio.aspx
```

It produced

```
audio.aspx   100%[===================>] 141.01K   105KB/s    in 1.3s
Removing audio.aspx since it should be rejected.
```

I have also tried

```
wget -r -c -nd -l1 --no-parent -A mp3,aspx http://ww2.example.com/audio.aspx
```

but that downloaded only aspx files and didn't download mp3 files.

> The `audio.aspx` file doesn't itself contain direct links to any mp3s
>   but it will contain links to other aspx pages which contain links to
>   the mp3 files that i want to download.

I want to download mp3 files from http://ww2.example.org/* (i.e. from whole website).

P.S: The **aspx** files here are static and are not dynamic web pages but are somehow named with aspx extension.

Edit: Even after trying the solution as stated in the comment, I got the same output. I think wget is somehow not able to identify the mp3 files in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all files (but not HTML) from a website using wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-but-not-html-from-a-website-using-wget)

Comment: @JoséLuis I tried that answer but the audio.aspx is downloaded as audio.aspx.html and it is rejected

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `-A mp3,aspx` and add `-p` to download page requisites. Let wget download everything and then use `find . -type f ! -iname "*.mp3" -delete` to remove all non-mp3 files.